# How to drag an item using NSItemProviderWriting using async

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

**Scenario:** The following Swift code uses `NSItemProviderWriting` to load a file from some data source async (The code actually just uses a `for` loop to simulate the time it needs to load the file). It returns the file url then. This code is used for drag & drop behavior in a macOS app from an app to another app. As the other app does only support file URLs as drop types, I can't send over the data itself.

```swift
class AnyFile: NSObject, NSItemProviderWriting {
    let url: URL
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [UTType.fileURL.identifier]
    }
    
    func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {
        let count = 100000
        let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: Int64(count))
        print("a")
        Task {
            print("b")
            for i in 0...100000 {
                progress.completedUnitCount = Int64(i)
                print(i)
            }
            print("c")
            completionHandler(url.dataRepresentation, nil)
            print("d")
        }
        print("e")
        return progress
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Drag & drop works, but when I start to drag the view (SwiftUI view using `.onDrag`), the view gets stuck as long as the loop is running. It is not clear to me why this happens as the loop us running inside a task. The console output also shows that `progress` is returned before the loop as finished. But still, it is stuck until the end of the loop. So the user experience is like not using async and the task.

*Log output (shortened)*

```
a
e
b
0
...
100000
c
d
```

**Actual Question:** Why is this Swift code for dragging files not behaving asynchronously even though it uses `Task`, `completionHandler`, and async/await constructs?

**Alternatives tried:**
I'm not bound to `NSItemProviderWriting` in particular. I have tried other ways, like `Transferable`, `.draggable()`, and `NSItemProvider.registerFileRepresentation`. But either they won't return a URL, or do not allow async at all. I also tried AppKit instead of SwiftUI with similar issues.